# Unzipping files using Shell Script

Tags: macos, shell-script, zip

All,
I have an app where  user picks up a zipped folder which a shell script unzips and then renames for processing. The zipped folder will always have the following naming convention: **"rXXXXX_CityName.info.zip"**.  The folder inside the zip file is named as **"CityName.info"**
When the shell script unzips the zip file, it will append the **"rXXXXX_"** to the folder name to create a folder called **"rXXXXX_CityName.info"**. 
Before unzipping ,the shell script checks if  a folder called **"rXXXXX_CityName.info"** exists, and deletes it if it does. 
Here is the code:

```
 THEZIPFILE="r12345_Boston.info.zip" 
 DIR="r12345_Boston.info"  
 if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
    rm -rf "$DIR"
    sleep 1
 fi  

 if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
    unzip -o "$THEZIPFILE" > /dev/null &
    zpid=$!
    wait $zpid
    EXIT_STATUS=$?
    if [ $EXIT_STATUS -eq 0 ]; then
        rm -rf  __MACOSX
        # Do Some processing....
    fi
    echo $EXIT_STATUS
    exit
else
    echo "-1"
    exit
fi
```

I want to know if this code leaves any room for mistakes? Am I right in assuming that the above code will execute sequentially(i.e wait for every command's completion before moving on to the next one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks OK, just seems some codes are unnecessary? For example, you can do `rm` directly and you can run `unzip` without `&` to wait.

```
 THEZIPFILE="r12345_Boston.info.zip" 
 DIR="r12345_Boston.info"  
 rm -rf "$DIR"
 unzip -o "$THEZIPFILE" > /dev/null
 EXIT_STATUS=$?
 if [ $EXIT_STATUS -eq 0 ]; then
   rm -rf  __MACOSX
   # Do Some processing....
 fi
 exit $EXIT_STATUS
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be more appropriate for  StackOverflow.

That said, you're probably on the right track, but I wouldn't do it that way.

Usually scripts wait till the sub-program exits, unless something specific is done to stop them, specifically, adding the `&` to the end of your `unzip` command tells the script to continue without waiting.  Then you have quite a bit of code to find out the process id of the command and wait until it finishes.

I'd suggest you simply remove it:

```
  unzip -o "$THEZIPFILE" > /dev/null
```

The `sleep` command after your `rm` also seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The script doesn't verify `$THEZIPFILE` exists before attempting to unzip it.  Also, if `$DIR` is a plain file and not a directory, it won't be removed before the unzip which will then give errors.

Comment: I posted a small part of the actual code.. I do all the checks in my shell script